# Extract 3 colors from JPEG and change it by 3 other

Tags: raster, r, jpg

I would like to import a JPEG image, find and extract 3 colors and change by 3 others to use as ID.

I can find the 3 colors I want by using Raster and I save the 3 images associated to these 3 colors. Then, I open these 3 JPEG images to combine in 1 using EBImage package. The image I got is not nice, the colors are indefinable.

[image]

I do not find the way to change these 3 colors in 3 others (by example I would like finally just red, green and blue to identify 3 items)

```
##################################################
#Plug it into a stack object using package raster

img <- list.files(folder) 
img.raster<-stack(img)
names(img.raster) <- c('r','g','b')

## Extract blue
img.blue<-img.raster
img.blue$blue<-0
img.blue$blue[img.blue$r<60 & img.blue$g<80 & img.blue$b<60] <- 1

## Extract grey
img.grey<-img.raster
img.grey$grey<-0
img.grey$grey[img.grey$r>85 & img.grey$g>82 & img.grey$b>77] <- 1

## Extract green
img.green<-img.raster
img.green$green<-0
img.green$green[img.green$r>65 & img.green$r<120
                  & img.green$g>90 & img.green$g<160
                  & img.green$b>45 & img.green$b<70] <- 1

#Export images using JPEG package
setwd("C:/Users/*******/export")
writeJPEG(as.array(img.grey), "grey.jpeg") 
writeJPEG(as.array(img.blue), "blue.jpeg") 
writeJPEG(as.array(img.green), "green.jpeg") 

#Open images using Using EBImage package
x <- readImage(file.choose())
y <- readImage(file.choose())
z <- readImage(file.choose())

#put 3 images in 1
total <- x + y + z

#Export images
writeJPEG(as.array(total), "total.jpeg")
```

Is it the good way or can it be done easily?

Comment: I think where you are going wrong is with `img.blue<-img.raster; img.blue$blue<-0` etc. That then means `img.blue` has four layers (r,g,b,blue) which means when you add them you aren't adding the new red, green, and blue components. Solution coming soon I think...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I'll make a test raster of all the colours from (0,0,0) to (255,255,255) in steps of 16:

```
> steps = seq(0,255, len=16)
> rgb = expand.grid(steps,steps,steps)
```

`rgb` is now all combinations of those 16 steps:

```
> dim(rgb)
[1] 4096    3
```

These are now to be packed into a 64x64 raster:

```
> sqrt(4096)
[1] 64
```

The red, green, and blue values:

```
> rr = raster(matrix(rgb[,1],64,64))
> gr = raster(matrix(rgb[,2],64,64))
> br = raster(matrix(rgb[,3],64,64))
```

Go into an RGB stack:

```
> img.raster = stack(rr,gr,br)
```

That's your source image. Plot it:

```
> plotRGB(img.raster)
> names(img.raster) = c("r","g","b")
```

[image]

Now I want to create three separate *single* layer rasters for each of the colours you want to extract. First the blue extraction.

```
> img.blue<-img.raster[[1]]   # **one layer**
> img.blue[] =0               # fill with zeroes
> img.blue[img.raster$r<60 & img.raster$g<80 & img.raster$b<60] <- 255
> plot(img.blue)
```

[image]

I'm not sure I believe this is the bluest pixels you are testing `$b < 60` which isn't particularly blue. Correct that if you have to.

Note I'm testing values from `img.raster` and putting them in the single layer `img.blue` and I'm putting the value 255 (not 1).

Repeat that for `img.grey` and `img.green`. Here's all three:

[image]

Now we want to create an RGB raster where the "grey" pixels are red, the "blue" pixels are green, and the "green" pixels are blue.

```
> replace = stack(img.grey, img.blue, img.green)
> plotRGB(replace)
```

[image]

Which I think is what you want.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks a lot for your really detailed answer